# IPython İnteractive Window in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-code, ipython, jupyter

I have created an anaconda environment within a Python interactive window in Visual Studio. I have installed the necessary 'ipython' and 'matplotlib' libraries. When I enable ipython and open the interactive window, I can't do anything. It just freezes when I hit enter. What could this be due to?
I get this error if I press reset to stop it freezing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether the package ipykernal is installed as well? I have once uninstalled the ipykernal package and encountered the same issue.

Besides, I also encounter quite a lot of problem when using interactive window with visual studio 2022 using global python 3.9 environment. But when I use the conda environment from the anaconda 2022 distribution, everything work perfectly.  I suspect it is a problem with the version of dependent packages.